# Button enabled and disabled based on status in ionic 2 using *ngIf condition

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic2

I am new to ionic 2 and Angular2. I have two buttons. I am getting the status from server like Boolean values true or false if it is a true I want to enable the button.

If I am getting the false I want to disable the button.

Please help me

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO! As you are new to SO, you might want to read the following help pages: ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert the desired value into ng-disabled

```
<button ng-model="button" ng-disabled="true">Button</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

try this code

```
isenabled=true;
isenabled=false;
```

this will work for if true then visible if false then hide.

```
<button ion-button [disabled]="!isenabled">my button </button>
```